# PCA -- Calculating Reduced Size Matrix With Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pca, eigenvector

I am trying to use PCA to reduce the size of an input image from 4096 x 4096 to 4096 x 163 while keeping its important attributes. However, there is something off with my method as I get incorrect results. I believe it is while constructing my matrix U. My results vs correct results are listed below.
Start code:

```
# Reshape data to 4096 x 163
X_reshape = np.transpose(X_all, (1,2,3,0)).reshape(-1, X_all.shape[0])
X = X_reshape[:, :163]

mean_array = np.mean(X, axis = 1)
X_tilde = np.reshape(mean_array, (4096,1))
X_tilde = X - X_tilde   

# Construct the covariance matrix for computing u'_i
covmat = np.cov(X_tilde.T)

# Compute u'_i, which is stored in the variable v
w, v = np.linalg.eig(covmat)

# Compute u_i from u'_i, and store it in the variable U
U = np.dot(X_tilde, v)

# Normalize u_i, i.e., each column of U
U = U / np.linalg.norm(U)
```

My results:

```
PC1 explains 0.08589754681312775% of the total variance
PC2 explains 0.07613195994874819% of the total variance
First 100 PCs explains 0.943423133356313% of the total variance

Shape of U: (4096, 163)
First 5 elements of first column of U: [-0.00908046 -0.00905446 -0.00887831 -0.00879843 -0.00850907]
First 5 elements of last column of U: [0.00047628 0.00048451 0.00045043 0.00035762 0.00025785]
```

Expected results:

```
PC1 explains 14.32% of the total variance
PC2 explains 7.08% of the total variance
First 100 PCs explains 94.84% of the total variance

Shape of U: (4096, 163)
First 5 elements of first column of U:  [0.03381537 0.03353881 0.03292298 0.03238798 0.03146345]
First 5 elements of last column of U:   [-0.00672667 -0.00496044 -0.00672151 -0.00759426 
-0.00543667]
```

There must be something off with my calculations, I just can't figure out what. Let me know if you need additional information.

Proof I am using:

[image: PCA Proof 1]

[image: PCA Proof 2]
[image: PCA Proof 3]

Comment: Why not use Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)? In any case include the MWE to produce your outputs.

Comment: One thing I'm curious about is why do PCA on a single image? Are you trying to implement a compression algorithm?

Comment: @lbragile should have mentioned that this is an assignment from a CS course I am taking. I do not get to choose the method I use. Prof wants us to use numpy and figure out how to implement this from scratch. I will edit the post to include the proof that I am following.

Comment: @jhill515 see above comment

Comment: @z.rubi, I get that the prof wants you to do things a certain way. Fun fact, numpy.linalg.svd() returns U matrix which are the eigen vectors of AA', and V matrix which are the eigen vectors of A'A. That said, you're justified in asking the prof to motivate the problem. That's why I was asking if you're trying to implement compression or are doing preconditioned dimensionality reduction for another learner. In a sense, if you're trying to reduce a 4096x4096 image to something with the same row-space, that seems very strange, even for a pet example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have the steps out of order. You're dropping dimensions from the input before you calculate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, so you're effectively randomly dropping a bunch of input at this stage with no justification.

```
# Reshape data to 4096 x 163
X_reshape = np.transpose(X_all, (1,2,3,0)).reshape(-1, X_all.shape[0])
X = X_reshape[:, :163]
```

I don't quite follow what the intent is behind the call to `transpose` above, but I don't think it matters. You can only drop dimensions from the input after calculating the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the covariance matrix. And you don't drop dimensions from the data explicitly; you truncate the matrix of eigenvectors and then use that reduced eigenvector matrix for the projection step.

The covariance matrix in this case should be a 4096x4096 matrix. The eigenvalues and eigenvectors will be returned in order, with the largest eigenvalue and corresponding eigenvector at the beginning. You can then truncate the number of eigenvectors to 163 and create the dimension-reduced projection.

It's possible that I've misunderstood something about the assignment, but I am pretty sure this is the problem. I'm reluctant to say more since it's homework.